# Why does Tensorflow spawn multiple threads (thread count 262) even when setting both inter_op_parallelism_threads and intra_op_parallelism_threads = 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a simple Tensorflow program (Keras API) to train a model on a single image (CPU only). Goal here is to understand how Tensorflow implements forward/backward pass under the hood in terms of model and/or data parallelism.
 Initially running with the default parameters, VTune Amplifier (Intel profiler) shows 421 threads being spawned. I then re-ran by setting both the inter_op_parallelism_threads and intra_op_parallelism_threads to 1 to force it to run on a single core. Even so, VTune shows 262 threads being spawned. 
Can someone please help me understand why so many threads are being spawned? Has this got anything to do with using Python API for Tensorflow?

I'm using Tensorflow 1.13 with python 3.6 on CentOS.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696900/why-tensorflow-creates-so-many-cpu-threads